# Hyperthreading Xeon CPU E5 2680 0 @ 2.7GHz

Tags: ethernet, intel, bandwidth, dmidecode

I'd like to verify whether my server set Hyper-threading, and the way to it.

`lscpu` shows Thread per core is "2"

`sudo dmidecode` shows HTT (Multi-threading).

```
I expected HTT (Hyper-threading technology), if Hyper-threading is enabled.
```

Please let me know to check Hyper-threading state and to make enable Hyper-threading.

And `lshw -c network` is different capacity 1Gbit/s with `ethtool eth0` 10GB/s
Why are those different? how to know correct network bandwidth?
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

`cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep 'cpu cores'` -- gives you number of real cores available

`cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep processor |wc -l` -- gives you number of 'fake' cores

If the numbers are the same, then you don't have HT enabled.
*this may not work on newer AMD processors but does on all manner of Intel processors from Xeon to i5*

Enabling HT depends on your server/motherboard/bios settings.

Your network card speeds are a mixed bag - you should provide a screen dump. Best guess, your network card is 10Gbit capable, but your network is not. It could be a switch that is not capable or connecting cable, or *other*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `lshw -c network` shows network0~1 >> Product : Solarflare Communications, capacity 1Gbit/s, logical name : eth0~1, and network0~4 >> Product: NetXtreme BCM5719 GIGABIT ETHERNET PCIe, capacity 1Gbit/s, logical name : em0~4. and I benchmark with another server 7Gbits/sec by `iperf -c server1 -t 30`. How is it possible? The device specification tell capacity 1Gbps

Comment: There is insufficient information in your reply to make an informed comment. Most likely scenario is that there is a virtual interface where channel bonding has been set up among physical adapters? Although your BCM card should only be able to handle ~4Gbps using its quad port...